Add a horizontal scrollbar to ngx-graph
I'm currently working with a large dataset that spans several years. I'm using ngx-graph to visualize it. The dataset is too wide to fit on a single page, so I'm looking for a way to add a horizontal scrollbar to ngx-graph. This will allow the user to view the entire dataset.
I have also tried setting a fixed width to the parent container, but it is not working with the zooming. I've also posted a question in the GitHub. Github issue
Can someone please assist me with this problem?
HTML code:
<div class="space-top-16 vc-form-container">
    <ngx-graph
        class="mss-graph-container"
        [layout]="dagreLayout"
        [curve]="curve"
        [links]="links"
        [nodes]="nodes"
        [autoZoom]="true"
        [autoCenter]="true">
        <ng-template #nodeTemplate let-node>
            <svg
                height="80"
                [attr.width]="node.data.children && node.data.children.length > 0 ? '112' : '72'"
                [attr.max-width]="112">
                <foreignObject
                    height="80"
                    [attr.width]="node.data.children && node.data.children.length > 0 ? '112' : '72'"
                    [attr.max-width]="112">
                    <div class="vc-mss-device-node-wrapper">
                        <div class="vc-mss-device-node" (click)="$event.preventDefault(); showWidget(node)">
                            <span
                                class="vc-mss-device-icon material-icons"
                                [style.border-color]="'#dadbdc'"
                                [style.color]="node.data.icon.color"
                                >{{ node.data.icon.label }}</span
                            >
                            <div
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                                class="vc-mss-device-node-text body-s-1"
                                [matTooltip]="node.label"
                                [matTooltipPosition]="'above'">
                                {{ node.label }} - {{ node.data.type }}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        @if (node.data.children && node.data.children.length > 0) {
                        <div class="vc-mss-device-node">
                            <button
                                mat-icon-button
                                class="vc-mss-device-expand-icon"
                                (click)="$event.preventDefault();
                                node.data.type !== 'INTERNET' ? (selectedNode = node) : (selectedNode = null)">
                                <mat-icon>{{ node.data.expanded ? 'expand_more' : 'expand_less' }}</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                            <span>({{ node.data.children.length }})</span>
                        </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </foreignObject>
            </svg>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #linkTemplate let-link>
            <svg:g class="edge" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path class="edge line mss-device-overview-line" [attr.d]="link.line"></path>
            </svg:g>
        </ng-template>
    </ngx-graph>
</div>

SCSS:
:host {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    .vc-mss-device-node-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 8px;
        padding: 8px;

        .vc-mss-device-node {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            gap: 8px;

            .vc-mss-device-icon {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                height: 36px;
                width: 36px;
                border: 1px solid;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }

            .vc-mss-device-node-text {
                width: 56px;
                text-align: center;
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
        }

        .vc-mss-device-node {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            gap: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;

            button.vc-mss-device-expand-icon {
                height: 24px !important;
                width: 24px !important;
                box-shadow: none !important;

                .mat-icon {
                    height: 24px;
                    width: 24px;
                    line-height: 24px;
                    font-size: 24px;
                }

                &.mat-mdc-icon-button:not([disabled]) {
                    &:hover,
                    &:focus-visible {
                        border-radius: 4px !important;
                        background-color: var(--primary-50);
                    }

                    &:focus-visible {
                        outline: 1px solid var(--primary-600);
                        outline-offset: 1px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .mss-graph-container {
        display: block;
        height: calc(100vh - 345px);
        width: 100%;
    }

    .mss-device-overview-line {
        stroke: var(--outline);
        stroke-width: 1;
    }

    .vc-mss-device-legend {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 8px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 32px;
        left: 16px;
        width: 150px;
        background-color: var(--ghost-white);

        .vc-mss-device-legend-item {
            display: inline-flex;
            align-items: center;
            gap: 8px;
        }
    }
}


ngx-graph adds the content inside a canvas, which means it is more of a drawing and the browser does not know it's size. However what you can do. is define a parent container, which which has scroll bars, and then render the much large ngx-graph inside this container, similar to this:
<div style="max-height: 256px;max-width:256px;overflow: scroll;">
          <canvas height="512px" width="512px"></canvas>
</div>

See: HTML canvas with scrollbar
However for this to work properly, you would need to know, the size of your data set. I am not sure if you can calculate this.
A much better option for you might be, to use the 'showMiniMap' feature of 'ngx-graph'.

I've tried both options but they did not work. So, I added buttons for the zoom-in and zoom-out
